# Viewing Retrieved Data from WebSQL in List

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to view data in list format from my database and each list contain the data which names of image I want to view. Here's the javascript code for retrieving

```
function querySuccess(tx,result){
    $('#batikPic').empty();
    $.each(result.rows,function(index){
        var row = result.rows.item(index);
        $('#batikPic').append('<li><img src="images/Real-Pattern/'+row['originalPattern']+'.jpg"/></li>');
      });
  $('#batikPic').listview();

}
```

and the HTML to view that is as follows

```
<div class="frame" id="basic">
            <ul class="clearfix" id="batikPic">


            </ul>
        </div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Because I am new to javascript programming. The list or image I want to view doesn't show up at all and when I checked in Google chrom inspect element, it says something like "the index must be in numbers"

Comment: 1) add data-role=listview to ul. 2) you need to refresh it after adding new items, use `.listview("refresh");`.

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't show anything. But thanks for the suggestions..